# I was reading about javascript functions/prototypes, and (fiddle provided)

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, prototype

I stumbled across a [section of code](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index2.html)<sup>1</sup> (at the bottom of the page, in the function prototype section) that I'm curious about:

```
function Employee(name, salary)
{
 this.name=name;                
 this.salary=salary;
}

/*line7*/ Employee.prototype.getSalary=function getSalaryFunction()
{
  return this.salary;
}

/*line12*/ Employee.prototype.addSalary=function addSalaryFunction(addition)
{
  this.salary=this.salary+addition;
}
```

1)I'm wondering if the same thing could be written as followed, and whether either one would be more functional?:

i)  add

```
this.getSalary = getSalaryFunction;
this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction;
```

to what I'm assuming is now the prototype (after the `name` and `salary` properties), 
and
ii) replace the original lines 7 and 12 respectively with:

```
function getSalaryFunction()
```

and

```
function addSalaryFunction(addition)
```

. Also, `/*return?*/Employee.salary+=addition;` would be shorthand for `this.salary = this.salary + addition;` in this case, right?

jsfiddle that represents my idea: http://jsfiddle.net/4fL8v69b/1/

<sup>1</sup>http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsFunc/index.html <sub>Web Developers Introduction To Features of JavaScript "Function" Objects</sub>.

Comment: "would be more functional?" --- what does it mean?

Comment: that's a simple magic of JavaScript for `encapsulation`; `this.salary` is not accessible from the object literal you've to produce simple `getters` and `setters` thus the `prototype` property of the `function` object is used..

Comment: the `prototype` property just makes the `function` and `variables` sort of `public` members to that object. And any `function` or `variable` attached directly to the `Employee` like `Employee.abc = 10` or `Employee.xyz = function(){};` will be `static` and `public` for every `Employee` object.

Comment: Why a downvote? And you're saying the original code and the fiddle would not work the same?

http://jsfiddle.net/4fL8v69b/

Comment: @PhilC. I didn't down vote you.. I tried to answer your question

Comment: Just want to know if the original code and the jsfiddle would run the same, and which one would process better if it would.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are adding the functions `getSalaryFunction` and `addSalaryFunction` to the global (or at least outer) scope, where they can be called independently (and probably return undefined.)

In the original example, the functions only exist as part of their parent object, so they are more likely to do the right thing* when called.

* I'm hand-waving over the complexities of `this` in JS.

Comment: I didn't even think about the `this` keyword outside of the prototype. Wow. So if I changed the functions from `return this.salary` etc. into `return Employee.salary` etc. (in the fiddle), would it be more likely to do what is expected?

Comment: Definitely not; that would refer to a property on the constructor itself, rather then the instance you create by calling `new Employee()`.